# Fatal error: Call to a member function login() on a non-object in

Tags: php, model, controller, member

Got an issue with a web app that I've inherited as a project and unfortunately I can't trace the error. It seems that the model isn't being loaded but I could be wrong. Any help would be great.

code is:

```
public function login()
{

    //If request is post then user is trying to login, so process the login info
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        //Run the model method ::login
        $login_successful = $this->User->login();

        // check login status
        if($login_successful) {
            // if YES, then move user to dashboard/index (btw this is a browser-redirection, not a rendered view!)
            header('location: ' . URL . 'passwords/index');
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect user / pass combination entered. Please try again.";
        }


    }

}
```

and the model function is:

```
public function login() {

    $username = $_POST['data']['User']['username'];
    $password = $_POST['data']['User']['password'];


    $bind = array(
        ":username" => "$username",
    );
    $result = $this->select("users", "username = :username", $bind);

    //Check the password returned from the db against the password entered
    if (Bcrypt::checkPassword($password, $result[0]['password']) == true) {
        Session::init();

        Session::set('user_logged_in', true);
        Session::set('user_id', $result[0]['id']);
        Session::set('user_name', $result[0]['username']);
        Session::set('user_permission', $result[0]['permission']);
        Session::set('user_role', $result[0]['role']);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

also I've noticed that the controller and model both have a function called login.]

Thanks

Comment: Have you load your user model properly?

Comment: @jamper which framework are you using?

Comment: Its a custom framework, but it looks like its taking aspects from cakePHP - have tried loading in the models the cakePHP way but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `$this->User` is not a valid class instance.

Make sure that it is an object.

Try

```
var_dump($this->User);
die();
//Run the model method ::login
$login_successful = $this->User->login();
```

And you will see that there is no instance there.

**What to do?**

Find the place where you expect your model being initialized. Check, why it is not.

Comment: Yes, getting null from the response.